# Creating a NativeScript custom UI plugin with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to create a custom UI plugin in TypeScript

Here's the steps I'm taking

1. create a plugin project in a local folder
2. write .ts files for custom UI in the plugin project root
3. generate .js files out of those .ts files with `tsc` command in the plugin project root
4. go to the test NativeScript project and run `tns plugin add <local plugin path>` to include the created plugin

But I get compiling errors at step 3 because I have importing statements as follows

```js
import { ContentView } from "ui/content-view";
import...
```

I referenced an example here https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-cardview/blob/master/cardview.ios.ts

My question is how cardview.ios.ts in the example 'nativescript-cardview' is being compiled to cardview.io.js? It seems impossible to do this...

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin, you have referenced the author has created a demo app and is using the declaration file for tns-core-modules from that demo. Look [at this line](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-cardview/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L10) where ***tns-core-modules.d.ts*** is included in **tsconfig.json**

You can follow this practice for testing cases and for your release you can create a relative path to the tns-core-modules (and references) declaration files from the app node_modules folder like done [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/files/nativescript-youtube-player/tsconfig.json#L13-L17)

As a side note [noEmiOnError](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L9) flag in your package.json will allow the translation to continue without hanging on errors.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with referencing files in typescript project,, Thank you for the answer. it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for linking to your repo. [NativeScript's docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins#create-a-plugin) state that "if you are using a transpiler, make sure to include the transpiled JavaScript files in your plugin".

Your package.json specifies cardview.js as the entrypoint, but your transpiled JavaScript files haven't been added to the repo. I solved this problem in my [nativescript-midi plugin](https://github.com/BinaryNate/nativescript-midi) by committing the transpiled files in a \dist directory. The plugin is written in ES 6 but transpiled to ES 5 for consumption. To make sure that the src and dist directories remain in sync, I use a git pre-commit hook that automatically runs the build command and commits the results. If you clone the nativescript-midi repo, you can view it in .git/hooks/pre-commit . A benefit of using this approach for your plugin is that it will also allow it to be used by developers who are not using TypeScript.